# Passing arrays as smaller than they actually are

Tags: arrays, fortran

In the following code, I declare an array `mass` with 20 elements.  When passed to the subroutine `foo`, `foo` is told that `mass` has only 10 elements.  However, I can still access the 20th element.  My questions are:

- Why can I pass an array to a subroutine and tell the subroutine the wrong size for the array?
- Why can I still access the 20th element even though the subroutine thinks it only has 10 elements?
- Would any changes I make to the 20th element in the array while in `foo` remain with the array just the same as if `foo` knew the proper size of the array?

Here is the code:

```
  program test
  implicit none

  integer num2,i
  real*8 mass(20)

  num2=10

  do i = 1,num
     mass(i) = 1.d0
  end do

  call foo(num2,mass)

  end


  subroutine foo(num2,mass)

  integer num2
  real*8 mass(num2)
  write(*,"(A20,E15.9)") "first one:",mass(1)
  write(*,"(A20,E15.9)") "tenth one:",mass(10)
  write(*,"(A20,E15.9)") "twentieth one:",mass(20)

  continue

  end
```

Note: This situation of a subroutine being told the wrong size for an array is one I am encountering in someone else's code I am trying to modify for my own usage.

Comment: Perhaps you can use an explicit interface (for example, by placing your subroutines in a module). This way you can check the size of the array by doing `SIZE(array)` at runtime and you won't have to worry about being passed the wrong size of an array.

Comment: @EMiller, thanks for the idea and maybe I will do that.  Unfortunately, this is a code written by someone else which is somewhat big and the situation I describe here happens in many places.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a couple of misconceptions underlying your question which I'll address in this answer.  Some practical implications are given in the [answer by M. S. B.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34522159).

You say that you declare an array `mass` with twenty elements, but that `foo` is told that it has only ten.  This is not correct.

What you have are actually two distinct entities: an array `mass` in the main program, with twenty elements, and an array (also called `mass`) of size ten in the subroutine `foo`.

The "passing" is establishing an association (so-called *argument association*) between those two entities.  The array called `mass` in the main program is the actual argument in the subroutine and the array called `mass` in the subroutine is the dummy argument.

The dummy argument is an array of explicit shape, extent `num2` (which is also argument associated with the `num2` of the main program).  The first `num2` elements of the dummy argument are associated with the first `num2` elements of the actual argument.  [This leads to the requirement that there are at least `num2` elements in the array in the main program.]

So, the answer to your first question

> Why can I pass an array to a subroutine and tell the subroutine the wrong size for the array?

is just this: you aren't telling it the wrong size, you are merely saying that the array in the subroutine corresponds to the first `num2` elements of the argument.

Coming to

> Why can I still access the 20th element even though the subroutine thinks it only has 10 elements?

This is a programming error.  You are not allowed to use a subscript value larger than the extent of the array.  What happens when you try this is up to the compiler.  As the other answer says, it's quite possible that this is just accessing (because of the way the association is implemented) that location in memory corresponding to the large element of the actual argument.  But equally the compiler could complain (especially with those checking compilation options chosen), or if the passing is done with temporary copying the thing could crash.  [This latter is unlikely.]

Finally

> Would any changes I make to the 20th element in the array while in foo remain with the array just the same as if foo knew the proper size of the array?

This is again implementation specific.  There is no correct Fortran answer, as your program isn't conforming.  As with the previous point, if that's an area of memory corresponding to the appropriate element of the actual argument and there's no bounds checking going on the changes could persist.  If the compiler chose to do a copy there could either be a crash or the changes outside the bounds could be ignored on return.  [Again, these last two are unlikely as it would require the compiler to be "clever".]

Answer (score 4):

*Why can I pass an array to a subroutine and tell the subroutine the wrong size for the array?*
Because Fortran allows you to use a portion of an array.

*Why can I still access the 20th element even though the subroutine thinks it only has 10 elements?*
Because 1) the array elements are consecutive in memory so the indexing reaches the 20th element, and 2) Fortran-produced programs normally doesn't check whether or not the programming is making performing invalid array subscripting.  Most compilers have options to insert such checks, e.g., `-fcheck=bounds` or `-fcheck=all` for gfortran.

*Would any changes I make to the 20th element in the array while in foo remain with the array just the same as if foo knew the proper size of the array?*
Yes.  If you did this and the original array didn't have 20 elements, you would alter an unrelated memory location, with bad results.